# Merge lists of different size with order

Tags: python

Is there a good way to merge lists like that:

```
L1 = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]

L2 = [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4]

L3 = [3.1, 3.2]
```

Result:

```
[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 1.3, 2.3, 2.4]
```

There should be no "None" elements in result.

**Edit**

Since it was marked as duplicate:
I do not need a result like this:

```
[(1.1, 2.1, 3.1), (1.2, 2.2, 3.2), (1.3, 2.3, None), (None, 2.4, None)]
```

I do not need any "None" elements. And the result should be one list.

Comment: There are not lists but sets. Edit your code properly

Comment: @Altoyr: No, check the result.

Comment: @KevinGuan You are right, my fault.

Comment: @AntonProtopopov This wasn't a code piece. More like a representation. Now it is.

Comment: @KevinGuan No, I need no None elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `izip_longest` from `itertools`:

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> L1 = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
>>> L2 = [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4]
>>> L3 = [3.1, 3.2]
>>> [x for sub in izip_longest(L1,L2,L3) for x in sub if x is not None]
[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 1.3, 2.3, 2.4]
```

Answer to the comment:

> What if the lists have None in them?

`None` is the default fillvalue:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(L1,L2,L3))
[(1.1, 2.1, 3.1), (1.2, 2.2, 3.2), (1.3, 2.3, None), (None, 2.4, None)]
```

If the lists can have `None` in them, use a fillvalue that cannot appear in the lists. For example:

```
>>> list(izip_longest(L1,L2,L3,fillvalue='my_awesome_fillval'))
[(1.1, 2.1, 3.1), (1.2, 2.2, 3.2), (1.3, 2.3, 'my_awesome_fillval'), ('my_awesome_fillval', 2.4, 'my_awesome_fillval')]
```

Answer (score 2):

To merge the lists

```
L1 = [1.1, 1.2, 1.3]
L2 = [2.1, 2.2, 2.3, 2.4]
L3 = [3.1, 3.2]
```

you can use the following one-liner

```
>>>  [x for y in map(None,L1,L2,L3) for x in y if x is not None]
[1.1, 2.1, 3.1, 1.2, 2.2, 3.2, 1.3, 2.3, 2.4]
```

Comment: That's a pretty clever use of map.